# Verify Your Identity - Wrong Mail Address

Tags: login-errors, identity, grant-login-access

It appears I have triggered my inability to log back into my developer org.

Received "You're trying to Log In to Salesforce. To make sure your Salesforce account is secure, we have to verify your identity.

Enter the verification code we emailed to di******************************@*****le.com."

The real problem here is that this is not my email and I can't receive the verification code. I don't know who added this email and how this email got there on the first place but it is really urgent and important for me to be able to login into my developer org.

Please advise what can be done and how to set the proper email address to receive the verification code.

Comment: Login form a computer where you previously logged in. Or login from an IP which you whitelisted, if you did it.

Comment: Contact an admin that has access to that org and ask them to change your email for you

Comment: If it is a free developer org then I doubt that you have many options as Salesforce are limited in their support for them and unless you have the other account details set up as an admin you would not be able to log in with that and change user settings.